# search by value and get key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've a object in mongoDB like this:

```
{
"key" : "something"
"meta" : {
        "pages" : {
            "0" : "http://test.com",
            "1" : "http://test2.com",
            "2" : "http://test3.com"
       }
    },
}
```

I need search "http://test2.com" and get it's key .

This is a very big object and i can't fetch all items and find key with code.
I need native mongodb query.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can text index pages and do `$text` search on it

or can convert the object to array using `$objectToArray` and find the matching element

```
db.t2.aggregate(
    [
        {$addFields : { keys : {$objectToArray : "$meta.pages"} }},
        {$project : {
                match : { $arrayElemAt : [  {$filter : {input : "$keys" , as : "k", cond : {$eq : ["$$k.v" , "http://test2.com"]} }}, 0] } 
             }
        }
    ]
)
```

result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a64678f66db54bf9993881f"), "match" : { "k" : "1", "v" : "http://test2.com" } }
```